# value <= maximum

Tags: python, bit, operations

I wonder, is it possible to achieve similar using bit operations:

```
if a > maximum: a = maximum
```

Where 'maximum' can be a random number?

Have many similar lines in my current code. Of course could have used:

```
def foo(a, max=512): return a if a<max else max
```

Just curious if there's a more elegant and efficient way.

Comment: How about using the built-in `min` function? `a = min(maximum, a)`, not a bit operation, but more elegant and concise.

Comment: @omz I'd submit that as an answer if I were you.

Comment: Bitwise operations will not result in more legance

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's no need to define your own function for this, `min` and `max` are already built-in:

```
a = min(maximum, a)
```

As per [Raymond's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10373703/573626), it is also possible to use bit operations:

```
a = maximum ^ ((a ^ maximum) & -(a < maximum))
```

But in the vast majority of cases, the performance benefit isn't really worth making the code very hard to understand. Also, this only works for integers, whereas the `min` function can be used for all comparable types.

Comment: Thanks, it's really the best option.

Answer (score 2):

Using *max* and *min* would make for clear code.

That being said, it is possible to use bit-twiddling:  http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#IntegerMinOrMax